# Python multiprocessing pool execution time compared to non-multiprocessing execution time

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am currently redesigning a program to use Python's multiprocessing pools. My first impression was that the execution time increased instead of decreased. Therefore, I got curious and wrote a little test script:

```
import time
import multiprocessing

def simple(x):
    return 2*x

def less_simple(x):
    b = x
    for i in range(0, 100):
        b = b * i
    return 2*x

a = list(range(0,1000000))

print("without multiprocessing:")
before = time.time()
res = map(simple, a)
after = time.time()
print(str(after - before))

print("-----")

print("with multiprocessing:")
for i in range(1, 5):
    before = time.time()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=i) as pool:
        pool.map(simple, a)
    after = time.time()
    print(str(i) + " processes: " + str(after - before))
```

I get the following results:

without multiprocessing:
2.384185791015625e-06

with multiprocessing:

1 processes: 0.35068225860595703

2 processes: 0.21297240257263184

3 processes: 0.21887946128845215

4 processes: 0.3474385738372803

When I replace simple with less_simple in lines 21 and 31, I get the following results:

without multiprocessing:
2.6226043701171875e-06

with multiprocessing:

1 processes: 3.1453816890716553

2 processes: 1.615351676940918

3 processes: 1.6125438213348389

4 processes: 1.5159809589385986

Honestly, I am a bit confused because the non-multiprocessing version is always some orders of magnitudes faster. Additionally, an increase of the process number seems to have little to no influence on the runtime. Therefore, I have a few questions:

1. Do I make some mistake in the usage of multiprocessing?
2. Are my test functions to simple to get a positive impact from multiprocessing?
3. Is there a chance to estimate at which point multiprocessing has an advantage or do I have to test it?

Comment: For small tasks the cost of spawning new processes will outweigh the time spent doing work. And there's no need for it in the first place either.

Comment: Your test functions are too simple. Spawning the processes and transfering the input and results is too expensive in relation to the actual computation.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research and basically, you are right. Both functions are rather small and somewhat artificial. However, there is a measurable time difference between non-multiprocessing and multiprocessing even for those functions, when you take into consideration how map works. The map function only returns an iterator yielding the results [1], i.e., in the above example, it only creates the iterator which is of course very fast.
Therefore, I replaced the map function with a traditional for loop:

```
for elem in a:
    res = simple(a)
```

For the simple function, the execution is still faster without multiprocessing because the overhead is too big for such a small function:

- without multiprocessing:

  - 0.1392803192138672
- with multiprocessing:

  - 1 processes: 0.38080787658691406
  - 2 processes: 0.22507309913635254
  - 3 processes: 0.21307945251464844
  - 4 processes: 0.2152390480041504

However, in case of the function less_simple, you can see an actual advantage of multiprocessing:

- without multiprocessing:

  - 3.2029929161071777
- with multiprocessing:

  - 1 processes: 3.4934208393096924
  - 2 processes: 1.8259460926055908
  - 3 processes: 1.9196875095367432
  - 4 processes: 1.716357946395874

[1] https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map